# Como obter os dias da semana atual ordenado de domingo/segunda

Tags: php

Tenho um grid de alguns apontamentos de horas que tenho um filtro pro usuário preenche a data e carrega meu grid com os registros e tenho um `<thead>` que tem os dias da semana, estou conseguindo buscar os dias corretos, porém fica assim:

```
Segunda 12
Terça   13
Quarta  14
Quinta  15
Sexta   9
Sabado  10
Domingo 11
```

Esta pegando dias de uma semana anterior, mas se eu clicar na quinta-feira ele ordena corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function diaSemana($variavel2, $dayName){
    if($variavel2 != null){
        $orderdate = explode('/', $variavel2);
        $day = $orderdate[0];
        $month   = $orderdate[1];
        $year  = $orderdate[2];

        $mes = date("m");
        $ano = date("YYYY");
        $dia = date("d");
        $dia_semana = date("w");


        $mes = $month;
        $ano = $year;
        $dia = $day;

    }

    $cont=0;

    While($cont<=6)
    {
        $dia_calendario = date("d/m/Y",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia-$dia_semana,$ano));
        $dia_s_calendario = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia-$dia_semana,$ano));

        if($dayName == $dia_s_calendario ){
            return $dia_calendario;
        }
        $dia_semana--;
        $cont++;
    }
}






<?php if(isset($_POST['variavel'])){?>                  
    <thead>
        <th id='thDomingo' class='trday'>DOMINGO<br><div id ='domingo' class='day' onclick='dataSemana(0)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),0); ?></th>
        <th id='thSegunda' class='trday'>SEGUNDA<br><div id ='segunda' class='day'onclick='dataSemana(1)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),1); ?></div></th>
        <th id='thTerca' class='trday'>TERÇA<br><div id ='terca' class='day' onclick='dataSemana(2)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),2); ?></div></th>
        <th id='thQuarta' class='trday'>QUARTA<br><div id ='quarta' class='day'onclick='dataSemana(3)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),3); ?></div></th>
        <th id='thQuinta' class='trday'>QUINTA<br><div id ='quinta' class='day' onclick='dataSemana(4)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),4); ?></div></th>
        <th id='thSexta' class='trday'>SEXTA<br><div id ='sexta' class='day' onclick='dataSemana(5)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),5); ?></div></th>
        <th id='thSabado' class='trday'>SÁBADO<br><div id ='sabado' class='day' onclick='dataSemana(6)'><?php echo $dias = diaSemana($variavel2 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$_POST['variavel']))),6); ?></div></th>                             
    </thead>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Os dias da semana corrente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte maneira, pego o dia atual, volto a data para o primeiro dia da semana e faço o loop até o domingo.

Ficou o seguinte código:

```
<?php

$translate = array(
    0 => "Dom",
    1 => "Seg",
    2 => "Ter",
    3 => "Qua",
    4 => "Qui",
    5 => "Sex",
    6 => "Sab",
);

$data = new DateTime('2017-12-12');     // Pega a data de hoje
$diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data->format('Y-m-d'))); // Dia da semana, começa em 0 com domingo, 1 para segunda...

$data->modify('-' . $diaN . ' day');

for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) {
    echo $data->format('d/m/Y') . ' - ' .  $translate[$data->format('w')] . "<br>";
    $data->modify('+1 day');
}
```

**Imagem do resultado do código acima:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom, a princípio funciona, mas acontece igual no meu código.

Tenta trocar:
$data = new DateTime');

Por:
$data = new DateTime('12-12-2017'); 

ele me retorna:

07/12/2017 - Qui
08/12/2017 - Sex
09/12/2017 - Sab
10/12/2017 - Dom
11/12/2017 - Seg
12/12/2017 - Ter
13/12/2017 - Qua

Se eu for ordernar isso, ficaria assim:


10/12/2017 - Dom
11/12/2017 - Seg
12/12/2017 - Ter
13/12/2017 - Qua
07/12/2017 - Qui
08/12/2017 - Sex
09/12/2017 - Sab

Comment: Fiz a correção, estava passando sempre o dia da semana como a data atual e não a data setada. Agora está correto. Antes deu certo pois era a data atual setada manualmente e pegava dinamicamente ela também.

Comment: Colega, obrigado por enquanto, já está dando uma baita força, porém ainda não gerou meu resultado, estou passando essa data por parâmetro.

EX:

$data = new DateTime($dataComboBox);

a variavel $dataComboBox recebe o valor de um input(datepicker) que o usuario seleciona, que após isso ele da um refresh na grid com ajax.

Comment: Você precisa formatar a data para o formato americano. Sendo "ANO-MES-DIA", no seu exemplo abaixo me parece que chegou "DIA-MES-ANO". Basta inverter as ordens, desta forma $data = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('-', $data))), desta forma, de "12-12-2017" será "2017-12-12".

Comment: Fiz o seguinte.

 $dataComboBox = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dataRecebida));
    $data = new DateTime($dataComboBox);     // Pega a data de hoje
    $diaN = date( "w", strtotime($data->format('Y-m-d'))); // Dia da semana, começa em 0 com domingo, 1 para segunda...

    $data->modify('-' . $diaN . ' day');

    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) {
        echo $data->format('d/m/Y') . ' - ' .  $translate[$data->format('w')] . "<br>";
        $data->modify('+1 day');
    }

Até o dia 13 ou segunda semana, ele me traz os valores corretamente. Após isso da erro na conversão e traz :

28/12/1969

Comment: Consegui colega, era a variável que estava vindo por parâmetro que tava no formato errado, tks.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, a princípio funciona, mas acontece igual no meu código.

Tenta trocar:

```
$data = new DateTime');
```

Por:

```
$data = new DateTime('12-12-2017');
```

ele me retorna:

07/12/2017 - Qui
08/12/2017 - Sex
09/12/2017 - Sab
10/12/2017 - Dom
11/12/2017 - Seg
12/12/2017 - Ter
13/12/2017 - Qua

Se eu for ordernar isso, ficaria assim:

10/12/2017 - Dom
11/12/2017 - Seg
12/12/2017 - Ter
13/12/2017 - Qua
07/12/2017 - Qui
08/12/2017 - Sex
09/12/2017 - Sab